# Ubuntu Plugins (gstreamer, freepats, etc) DEB Archive?

Tags: files, deb, plugins

Correct me if I'm wrong (I'm still a newb, tried Ubuntu last year), but I made a fresh install of Natty. Is there an Ubuntu site where it has the *.deb files of restricted plugins? i.e. gstreamer, freepats, and the like for a specific Ubuntu distro. My net speed sucks most of the time, just for backups or something.

Comment: related with this question http://askubuntu.com/q/974/61218

Answer (score 2):

Basically most of the retricted packages are on ubuntu repository. Just search for your package on http://packages.ubuntu.com/. There are some additional media packages not found in main repository here: http://medibuntu.org/. As for backup, the installed packages that were installed with `apt` stay on `/var/cache/apt/archives` You may backup that on any external device or somewhere else so that you can reuse it later.

Comment: thanks man, now there's a use for my spare flash drives lol

Answer (score 0):

Yes, http://packages.ubuntu.com . Choose your Ubuntu version, search the package, then on the right choose your download.

Comment: will bookmark that to be used in the future. thanks

Comment: there's a message that goes like, "it's recommended that you install it from the local repositories." it doesn't matter, right?

Comment: Those packages are from the repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Probably in the launchpad repository: http://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty .
Just search the package you would like to install and download it.
If you would like to use gstreamer, I advice you to add this medibuntu repository, please see here : http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/medibuntu . To easely install repository and application, install ubuntutweak : http://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak  .

Answer (score 0):

The `apt` is not the only tool which store installed (actually downloaded) debs in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, but also  `synaptic` and Software-Center. Just a clarification.

But if you want to install these packages later, you should setup a local-repository, so that you do not need to download these debs again.

You can get details about creating a **personal repository** [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Personal).

It is fine, if you do not stay connected to the Internet. But the problem with this method is  - it is not [**trusted**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SecureApt#Basic_Concepts). So if you want to install a package which resides both on your *untrusted* 'personal repository' and also on a trusted repository on the Internet, the package manager(`apt` or `synaptic`) will try to download the packages from trusted one (from Internet). So you may want to setup a **local trusted repository**. You can create a trusted repository by following [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1090731) guide.

If it seems to you a clumsy method, you can force to install from your *untrusted local repository* by using `--allow-unauthenticated` switch to `apt-get` or change the preference of `synaptic`.

#### apt-get method

`sudo apt-get --allow-unauthenticated install your_package_name`

#### synaptic method

when you check some package to install and click on **Apply** button, synaptic will warn you that *the packages are not authenticated* and ask 'are you want to continue?'. just say OK to this answer.